# angular ngrx state array item update when Id match

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I want to know how can I add item - if does not exist - or update - if item does exist with matching id - inside ngrx state array `initialState.calls`. Below example for investigate. In whole web there is no proper universal example how to do it.

```
export interface Call {
  timestamp: number;
  call_id: string;
  tag: Tag[];
}

export default interface KeywordsModel {
  version: string;
  calls: Call[];
  isOpen: boolean;
  lastUpdatedOn: number;
}

 export const initialState: KeywordsModel = {
   calls: [],
   lastUpdatedOn: Date.now()
 };

export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(KeywordsWebSocketActions.messageReceived, (state, { message, timeReceived }) => ({
    ...state,
    ...message,
    lastUpdatedOn: timeReceived
  })),
  on(KeywordsWebSocketActions.keywordsPageOpened, state => ({ ...state, isOpen: true })),

  // Here I need to create action 'messageCallReceived' below doesnt work
  on(KeywordsWebSocketActions.messageCallReceived, (state, { call }) => ({
    ...state, calls: (state.calls.map((existCall: Call) => (existCall.call_id === call.call_id) ? existCall = call : [...state.calls, call])),
  }))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use NgRx Entity and make it handle this process for you. but in case you want to handle it manually then I hope the following examples help you on mutating the array.
taking example we have array of objects

```
let arr = [{id:1},{id:2}];
```

```
//Check if item with id=1 exists 
let itemExists = arr.findIndex(x=>x.id==1) >= 0; //true if exist, else false


//Add at the begin
arr = [newItem,...arr];

//Append to the last
arr = [...arr,newItem];

//insert at index i
arr = [...arr.slice(0,index),newItem,...arr.slice(index)[


//Removing item with id match
let toRemoveId=1;
arr = arr.filter(a=>a.id!=toRemoveId)

//Updating item with id=1
arr = arr.map(a=>a.id==1 ? updatedEntity : a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ngrx/entity for that Calls array see here https://ngrx.io/guide/entity. Then you can use upsert action to add or update https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter.